# FFMPEG Adding Metadata to an .mp3 From .mp3 Input?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, metadata, kubuntu

If I start off with  a .mp3 file, how can I add metadata to it? I'm aware of the `-metadata title="Some Title" -metadata artist="Someone"` formatting, but not sure how this can be applied to a .mp3 file, especially if the file is already a .mp3.

I'm thinking something more like this: `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -metadata artist="Someone" -f mp3 output.mp3`

The only thing is that when I execute this with ffmpeg 4 compiled with all libraries on Kubuntu 18.04, I get this error message:

> Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format mp3 (codec mp3) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
> Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0

**Edit:**

This also happens when I try to add `-acodec libmp3lame` although the error seems to indicate that I don't have the .mp3 codec

```
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~/Desktop/Indexing/Test Folder$ ffmpeg -i DANCE\ WITH\ THE\ DEAD\ -\ BATTLE.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 file.mp3
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'DANCE WITH THE DEAD - BATTLE.mp3':
  Duration: 00:04:15.92, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
    Side data:
      replaygain: track gain - -9.200000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown, 
Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your ffmpeg build does not have any MP3 encoder. However, for your use case, that's irrelevant.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c copy -metadata artist="Someone" output.mp3
```

Output has to be a separate file. FFmpeg can't update the input itself.

Comment: You can repeat the `-metadata` argument for more than one item (e.g. `-metadata artist="artist name" -metadata title="track title"`). You can see a partial metadata tag list at https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/FFmpeg_Metadata#MP3

Answer (score 2):

I have hundreds of files, and I use this script. 
I hope will be helpful for someone.

[Github](https://github.com/firedevelop/id0000512-Scripts-for-Audio-Clean-Edition-Master-PosProduction/tree/master/id0000511-Script-Audio-add-tags-id3tags-metadata)

[Github with some audio scripts](https://github.com/firedevelop/id0000512-Scripts-for-Audio-Clean-Edition-Master-PosProduction)

[YouTube Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdbMQ5CoohNhTgXTbdRfOUC_aFlEbHTL)

```
#!/bin/sh

#____________ 1. CONVERT ALL WAV FILES TO 44100hz and 16bits _______________________________
# Rename all audio wav files in folder, with the format 001.wav, 002.wav, 003.wav, etc...
a=1
for i in *.wav; do
  new=$(printf "%03d.wav" "$a") #03 pad to length of 3
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done

rm *.mp3    # remove old mp3 files

declare -a arr=("" # always keep empty the first array index, because have index zero.
                "Track Title 1 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 2 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 3 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 4 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 5 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 6 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 7 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 8 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 9 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 10 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 11 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                "Track Title 12 (allow with special characters + $ ñ ò)"
                )

counterTotalFiles = 0;    # count the total audio wav files there are in the folder
counterTrackNumber = 0;   # sequence of the track number
metadataArtist = "My Artist Name"
metadataTPE2="My Artist Album"
metadataComposer="My Composer"
metadataGenre="Spoken & Audio" 
metadataYear=`date +%Y`   # setup automatic the current year


# count the total audio wav files there are in the folder
for x in *.wav; do      
  let counterTotalFiles++
done

  for z in *.wav; do      
    let counterTrackNumber++
    ffmpeg -y -i "$z" -vn -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -metadata title="${arr[$counterTrackNumber]}" -metadata album="My Album Name" -metadata track="$counterTrackNumber/$counterTotalFiles" -metadata artist="$metadataArtist" -metadata TPE2="$metadataTPE2" -metadata composer="$metadataComposer" -metadata genre="$metadataGenre" -metadata year="$metadataYear" $z.mp3
  done

# remove temporary files
rm "temp-"*.wav    
rm *.pkf    

# rename the wrong extension *.wav.mp3 to the right extension *.mp3
for f in *.mp3; do
    mv -- "$f" "$(basename -- "$f" .wav.mp3).mp3"
done


# show info about your media files generated
mediainfo *.mp3
ls -lah
```

Comment: Thanks (I guess?) for the complete, working script, but it might be more helpful to (1) present and explain the ``ffmpeg`` command at the core of the script, and (2) explain the rest of what the script is doing.  Also, (3) when you have a command that’s 352 characters long, it’s nice to break it up into shorter lines.  And (4) I noticed that your `ffmpeg` command quotes `"$z"` (and `"$metadataTPE2"`, `"$metadataComposer"`, `"$metadataGenre"` and `"$metadataYear"`) but not `$z.mp3`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (5) Finally, most importantly, it looks like your ``ffmpeg`` command takes `.wav` files as input and produces `.mp3` files as output.  But the question asks how to *take **`.mp3` files as input*** and produce `.mp3` files as output.  (6) P.S. [Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) is specified by POSIX, but `let` and `++` are not.  (7) P.P.S. How can that script even work when it says things like ``counterTotalFiles = 0`` (with spaces)?